# Rails render formats haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have two files

```
/show.html
/show.html.haml
```

when I am trying to render the haml file it doesn't work.

```
render :show, :formats => [:html] #works
render :show, :formats => [:haml] #doesn't work, Missing template error
```

Comment: Rename `show.html.haml` to `show.haml`

Answer (score 0):

`haml` is not the format, is the handler, the format is still `html`

Do this: `render :show, formats: [:html], handlers: [:haml]`